# Multiple regression table size stargazer to LaTex

Tags: r, latex

I am struggling with the following. I have a certain output in RStudio which I try to export to LaTex however I struggle with the length as the tables gets really large and extends out of the view of the page.

I am not able to neatly introduce it to my LaTex file. Is there a way I can either stack the regression output on top of eachother or make it fitting onto a LaTex page whithout making the font unreadable

```
OLS1 <- lm(score ~ Treatment, data = Data)
OLS2 <- lm(score ~ Treatment + iq, data = Data)
OLS3 <- lm(score ~ Treatment + iq + factor(ses), data = Data)
OLS4 <- lm(score ~ Treatment + iq + factor(ses) + depression, data = Data)
OLS5 <- lm(score ~ Treatment + iq + factor(ses) + depression + male, data = Data)
OLS6 <- lm(score ~ Treatment + iq + factor(ses) + depression + male + schoolid, data = Data)
OLS7 <- lm(score ~ Treatment + iq + factor(ses) + depression + male + schoolid + persnr, data = Data)
OLS8 <- lm(score ~ Treatment + iq + factor(ses) + depression + male + schoolid + persnr + combined_month, data = Data)
stargazer(OLS1, OLS2, OLS3, OLS4, OLS5, OLS6, OLS7, OLS8, type = "text")
```

This is how the output looks in LaTex at the moment
[LaTex output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1USjW.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

I tried making seperate stargazer outputs so split it up into 2 parts however this results me into having 2 seperate tables